# Chart.js animations when updating chart data

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, chart.js

I'm currently working with Chart.js, and I need to change between two differents datasets. To do this I just change the dataset and use the Update function.
The main problem is that when you change multiple times between the datasets, the animation dissapears and it looks horrible.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/nuzegivilo/4/edit?html,js,output) you can see what I'm talking about and my code.
Does somebody know how could I fix it?
Thanks a lot!

And here is my code, in case the link doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chart.js Example</title>
    <!-- import plugin script -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- bar chart canvas element -->
    <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <button onclick="manageCharts()" id="chartDataButton">Chart 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code

```
  Chart.defaults.global.responsive = false;

  var chartData1 = {
    labels : ["L1", "l2", "l3", "l4"],
    datasets : [{
        label: "LEGEND",
        data : [13, 23, 9, 4],
        backgroundColor: "#FF88CC",
        borderColor: "#000000",
        borderWidth: 1,
    }]
  }

  var chartData2 = {
    labels : ["L11", "L12"],
    datasets : [{
        label: '{{ legend }}',
        data : [7, 1],
        backgroundColor: "#FEFE65",
        borderColor: "#00FFFF",
        borderWidth: 2,
    }]
  }

  var pieChartOptions = {
    rotation: -Math.PI,
    cutoutPercentage: 30,
    circumference: Math.PI,
    legend: {
      position: 'left'
    },
    animation: {
      animateRotate: true,
      animateScale: false
    }
  };

  // get chart canvas
  var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");

  var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: chartData1,
    options: pieChartOptions
  });

  function manageCharts(){
    var button = document.getElementById("chartDataButton");
    var previousData = pieChart.config.data;

    if(previousData == chartData1){
      button.textContent = "Chart 1";
      showChart2Data();
    }else if(previousData == chartData2){
      button.textContent = "Chart 2";
      showChart1Data();
    }
  }

  function showChart2Data(){
    pieChart.config.data = chartData2;
    pieChart.update();
  };

  function showChart1Data(){
    pieChart.config.data = chartData1;
    pieChart.update();
  };
```

Comment: Ok, so could you please help me? @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw0o0v5z/) to use the `destroy()` function.

Using `update()` doesn't seem reset the animation.

Using `destroy()` removes the chart and then your code will recreate the new chart (and animation)

PS: Sorry for changing to jsfiddle from JS Bin.  I was having troubles editing in JS Bin.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `destroyChart` in the code? I see the definition, but not the actual usage.

Comment: This fiddle doesn't work as expected, switching the charts a few times crashes it